# How to create a function (in BigQuery SQL) performing a windowing operation on a table?

Tags: google-bigquery

While operating on tables containing domain events, I regularly want to get the latest row (event) of some ID column.

Minimal example:

```sql
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT 1 AS thing_id, 123 AS some_value, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:00:00') AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 234, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:01:00') AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 345, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:02:00') AS event_timestamp )
/* Get the latest event per thing_id. */
SELECT
  DISTINCT(thing_id),
  FIRST_VALUE(some_value) OVER win event_timestamp,
  FIRST_VALUE(event_timestamp) OVER win event_timestamp,
FROM
  events
WINDOW
  win AS (
  PARTITION BY
    thing_id
  ORDER BY
    event_timestamp DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
```

Instead of repeating this pattern every time, I'd like to abstract it into a function, so that I can use it slimiarly to the following:

```sql
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT 1 AS thing_id, 123 AS some_value, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:00:00') AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 234, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:01:00') AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 345, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:02:00') AS event_timestamp )
SELECT * FROM functions.get_latest_row_by(events, thing_id, event_timestamp)
```

My current attempt (which does not work), looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION functions.get_latest_row_by(table, key_col STRING, timestamp_col STRING) AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT column_name,
    FIRST_VALUE(*) OVER win *
  FROM
    table_name
  WINDOW
    win AS (
    PARTITION BY
      user_id
    ORDER BY
      column_name DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) )
```

Is it possible to achieve this, or am I doomed to be non-DRY with this logic?

Comment: if you want to pass table name - you will end up with using `execute immediate` which is not allowed in UDFs but allowed to be used within `procedure` . so you can use procedure to pass table name and whatever else you need as IN params and have result as OUT param. Note: in this case you will not be able to wrap all in one query - you will rather need to use scripts

Comment: As @MikhailBerlyant mentioned this is not possible using one script, since in a table function you cannot call a table name to use it as a parameter.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks! Looks like I will learn some new concepts then. :-)